# Reuse the log create in Main() in other classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, serilog

I define my log in the main class the following way:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(string.Format("log/log-{0}.txt",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss")), outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] ({SourceContext}.{Method}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] ({SourceContext}.{Method}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();
```

But, the `Main()` method of my console application is not the only place I would like to log. I'd like to reuse the same log file for my other classes as well so that each run of the application will create one file only in which all the logs from different classes for that specific run is inserted.

How can I tell a class e.g. `DatabaseController` to use the same log I defined in `Main()`?

Answer (score 0):

1- One best way to avoid having multiple log files and only a global one, is to declare `Log.Logger` in the class, so all the methods inside the class will use the same log, you can also use it from method outside the current class if you make it public

here's an example:

```
class Program {
    LoggerConfiguration ex = null; \\ or make it public if you want to call the log outside the local class

    void Main(){
        ex = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(string.Format("log/log-{0}.txt",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss")), outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] ({SourceContext}.{Method}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] ({SourceContext}.{Method}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();
        Method();
    }

    void Method() {
        ex.WriteTo.File(string.Format("/"));
    }
}
```

2- You can also send the log file to the method as a parameter.

```
LoggerConfiguration ex = new LoggerConfiguration();
Method(ex);
```

And the method parameter should be for example

```
int Method(LoggerConfiguration ex)
{
    // rest of your code
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: The first approach I could not really implement. Because if we want to have logger as a global variable then they have to be static and **Serilog** afaik, cannot be initialized statically. / The second approach does not go well with Dependency Injection principles, altering every method to carry a log object. For now, I'm afraid I resorted to my own logging routine.

Answer (score 0):

I think Serilog by default works the way you wanted with a static global logger.  Log.Logger sets that up and then after that you just have a "using Serilog;" in your `DatabaseController` class and can either do:

```
Log.Verbose("Hello World");
```

Or if you want more context:

```
using Serilog;

class DatabaseController
{
    static ILogger logger = Log.ForContext<DatabaseController>();

    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        logger.Verbose("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Either will write to the sinks that have been defined in your `Main()`.